# Getting duplicate and sum its integer values

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am getting a list from this :

```
items = [[slot['accountLabelType'], slot['totalPrice']] for slot in self.data]
```

This yields a list like this :

```
['Transport', 888]
```

Now, on this list there are duplicates and what I want to do is to identify the duplicates and sum its values. I have read that you can find duplicates on a list with `collections.Counter`, I am trying to do :

`c = [y for y in Counter(self.data) if y > 1]`

but I get the error

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Group by and sum a list of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058001/python-group-by-and-sum-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: a list is not hashable...counter is a `dict` subclass and expects hashable items as the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict(int)
for slot in self.data:
    c[slot['accountLabelType']] += slot['totalPrice']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have created a dictionary in the beginning and sum `totalPrice` field as you iterate:

```
items = {}
for slot in self.data:
    label = slot['accountLabelType'] 
    price = slot['totalPrice']
    if label in items:
        items[label] += price
    else:
        items[label] = price
print items
```